# How to create a dummy QQuickItem in C++ at runtime

Tags: qt, unit-testing, googletest, qquickitem

I am using `Qt 5.7` & unit testing using `gtest` or as its called [googletests](https://github.com/google/googletest).

I have a function to test which intakes a `QQuickItem`. To test this, I **want to create a `QQuickItem` on fly when my unit test in run**. *Is it possible?*

Note that I do have access to `QQmlApplicationEngine` or the any qml files like `main.qml`. However I should be able to create a `dummy.qml` in the resources of my tests project ?
I also thinking that doing a `#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>` should give me access to `QQmlApplicationEngine` ?

**How do I create dummy `QQuickItem` in C++ code *with some valid width & height* in my unit test, & pass it to my method at runtime?**

Comment: You will still be using QML, just that instead of a stand-alone file you'll pass the QML script directly to the engine, as a `QString`.

Comment: @KubaOber - I don't think this is an option from C++. There are additional requirements for visible objects, including `QQuickItem` which doesn't have any default graphical representation but is a visible item nonetheless - you have to `setParentItem(someVisualItemPointer)`.

Comment: Note that there is `void QQmlComponent::setData(const QByteArray &data, const QUrl &url)` which you can use to create a qml component out of a source string.

Comment: There's no way to use QML without, well, using QML. Instantiating any QML objects from C++ requires passing QML that instantiates those objects to the QML engine. The QML script can be generated at runtime if you wish so, of course. There's this sorry idea that somehow if only you could "instantiate" a QML object from C++ using `new`, things would be peachy. Alas, just think about it: such objects would be typically useless as there's no C++ APIs to do anything useful with them - you can't set bindings, you can't access all of the QML properties, etc. You want QML, you have to use it!

Comment: Yeah, I have been a pretty vocal opponent of doing anything QML from C++. It only "makes sense" if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: There is however the `setContextForObject()` function and the question what is its purpose. I mean the "traditional means" to create a QML object from C++ all set the context, even if you don't pass a context, the root context will be used. And setting a context works only if you don't have a context, and it is a public API function, so presumably there might be some way to create an object and have it associated with the engine.

Comment: there is no way to `qml_engine->load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/dummy.qml"))` & get valid view? or some kind temporary view that lives only within my test function?

Comment: You will have an isolated qml engine with that single QML file loaded in it, not very useful IMO, but if that's what you want, it is perfectly doable. However, if you use `QQmlApplicationEngine ` your root will have to be an `ApplicationWindow`. Maybe try with `QQuickView` instead, they you can have any qml tyle as a root.

Comment: @dtech is there a sample you can point me too or an answer ? any-way is fine for me. just need a valid `qquickitem` in my unit-test function.

Comment: `QQuickItem *dummy_view = qml_engine->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("DummyViewObject")` - Using this complains `item is not attached to a window`. Can provide it a window on the fly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to have an isolated `QQuickItem` object for testing would be to use a `QQuickView`:

```
QQuickView * view = new QQuickView;
view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/dummy.qml")));
QQuickItem * dummyItem = view->rootObject();
```

Due to popular demand:

```
// dummy.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
  width: 200
  height: 200
}
```

Comment: can you give your example of `dummy.qml` ? I get an error complaining `item has invalid dimensions`. something still missing :(

Comment: please add the `dummy.qml` to your answer